# My Clipboard.GetText() not working please help... (Windows Phone)

Tags: gettext

Why is this not working. i am pasting normal string...

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox02.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

Comment: **How** is it not working? What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clipboard.GetText` is not available to Windows Phone applications. MSDN states:

> You cannot get clipboard text from a Windows Phone application, only set it. Calling the GetText method in a Windows Phone application will always cause a SecurityException to occur.
>
> [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28VS.95%29.aspx)

I am not aware of any way to read the clipboard data in Windows Phone.